# setInterval() causing maximum stack call size exceeded error?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm getting a "maximum stack call size exceeded" error after running the code below for a while. `setInterval()`should be able to run recursively seamlessly, so I'm not yet sure that the error is being caused by it or another part of the code.

```
function blinkCursor() {
    $("#cursor").animate({opacity: 0}).animate({opacity: 1});
} setInterval(blinkCursor, 600);
```

Here is the last part of the code. But I tested it without the part above and had no problems. In any case, now I'm not that sure.

```
function type() {
    var firstSentence = "Human rights",
        firstSentenceCounter = 0,
        intervalID = setInterval(typeWithDelay, 150);

    function typeWithDelay() {
        $("#text").text(firstSentence.substring(0, firstSentenceCounter++));

        if(firstSentenceCounter == firstSentence.length+1) {
            clearInterval(intervalID);
        }
    }
} setTimeout(type, 1500);
```

Comment: If you're calling something recursively, you would not use setInterval.

Comment: how long is "for a while"? currently testing this and had no problems for a few minutes

Comment: Frankly, "for a while" is a lot. I've done lots of other stuff (away from the computer for more than 20 min., probably), came back and checked the console to find it out. It's probably much more than any user would perceive if it wasn't a blinking cursor that stops blinking when the error appears.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`animate()` default duration is 400.

You are continually calling function long before animations are complete and continually adding to the animation queue which never stops growing.

400+400 = 800 ... greater than 600 interval currently used

A far better approach would be to use last animation callback to intitialize next round instead of using `setInterval`

```
function blinkCursor() {
    $("#cursor").animate({opacity: 0}).animate({opacity: 1}, blinkCursor );
}
blinkCursor(); // initialize once
```

Comment: I got the point and changed the code, but for some reason the blinking is not taking place anymore. Any idea?

Comment: will need to call `blinkCursor()` once yourself to get it started, if you want delay on that first one can use setTimeout for it

Comment: Perfect, it works. Would have to wait to check about the error, but I don't think there's any problem. ) Tks!

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are trying to implement the typewriter effect. This can merely done using CSS. No need to write JavaScript for that unless you are supporting old browsers such as IE7.

Checkout the link below:

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/typewriter-effect/

Comment: Solution is a good concept but link only answers are not very valuable. Links should only be used as reference to code that actually exists in the answer

Comment: Thanks for that. But I'm doing via js for training purposes.